How to solve the Exception: System.Exception error on build with COSMOS on VS2022?
I was making an OS in COSMOS after i heard about it. I have some knowledge on C#. But somehow, there is a build error in the switch(cmd) part.
The switch part:
            switch (cmd)
            {
                case "mkdir":
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(arg))
                    {
                        FileOperations.CreateDirectory(arg);
                        Console.WriteLine($"Directory '{arg}' created.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Usage: mkdir <directory>");
                    }
                    break;

                case "ls":
                    FileOperations.ListFilesAndDirectories(filepath);
                    break;

                case "rm":
                    if (FileOperations.FileExists(arg))
                    {
                        FileOperations.DeleteFile(arg);
                        Console.WriteLine($"File '{arg}' deleted.");
                    }
                    else if (FileOperations.DirectoryExists(arg))
                    {
                        FileOperations.DeleteDirectory(arg);
                        Console.WriteLine($"Directory '{arg}' deleted.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"File or directory '{arg}' not found.");
                    }
                    break;

                case "ren":
                    var renameArgs = arg.Split(' ', 2);
                    if (renameArgs.Length == 2)
                    {
                        FileOperations.RenameFile(renameArgs[0], renameArgs[1]);
                        Console.WriteLine($"Renamed '{renameArgs[0]}' to '{renameArgs[1]}'.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Usage: ren <oldname> <newname>");
                    }
                    break;

                case "cp":
                    var copyArgs = arg.Split(' ', 2);
                    if (copyArgs.Length == 2)
                    {
                        FileOperations.CopyFile(copyArgs[0], copyArgs[1]);
                        Console.WriteLine($"Copied '{copyArgs[0]}' to '{copyArgs[1]}'.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Usage: cp <source> <destination>");
                    }
                    break;

                case "mv":
                    var moveArgs = arg.Split(' ', 2);
                    if (moveArgs.Length == 2)
                    {
                        FileOperations.MoveFile(moveArgs[0], moveArgs[1]);
                        Console.WriteLine($"Moved '{moveArgs[0]}' to '{moveArgs[1]}'.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Usage: mv <source> <destination>");
                    }
                    break;


                default:
                    Console.WriteLine($"Command '{cmd}' not recognized.");
                    break;
            }

For those who wonder FileOperations is this:
using Sys = Cosmos.System;

public class FileOperations
{

    public static void CreateFile(string path)
    {
        using (var file = File.Create(path)) { }
    }

    public static void WriteToFile(string path, string content)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(path, content);
    }

    public static string ReadFromFile(string path)
    {
        return File.ReadAllText(path);
    }

    public static void DeleteFile(string path)
    {
        File.Delete(path);
    }

    public static void CreateDirectory(string path)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }

    public static void DeleteDirectory(string path)
    {
        Directory.Delete(path, true);
    }

    public static bool FileExists(string path)
    {
        return File.Exists(path);
    }

    public static bool DirectoryExists(string path)
    {
        return Directory.Exists(path);
    }

    public static void RenameFile(string sourcePath, string destPath)
    {
        File.Move(sourcePath, destPath);
    }

    public static void CopyFile(string sourcePath, string destPath)
    {
        File.Copy(sourcePath, destPath, true);
    }

    public static void MoveFile(string file, string newpath)
    {
        File.Copy(file, newpath);
        File.Delete(file);
    }
    public static void ListFilesAndDirectories(string path)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Directory '{path}' not found.");
            return;
        }

        var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(path);

        Console.WriteLine("Directories:");
        foreach (var dir in directories)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"  {Path.GetFileName(dir)}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Files:");
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"  {Path.GetFileName(file)}");
        }
    }
}

I tried debugging the functions, but it did no help.
EDIT: I got the build output:
1>------ Build started: Project: OS, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\9.0.100-preview.7.24407.12\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.RuntimeIdentifierInference.targets(326,5): message NETSDK1057: You are using a preview version of .NET. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-support-policy
1>Skipping analyzers to speed up the build. You can execute 'Build' or 'Rebuild' command to run analyzers.
1>OS -> C:\Users\Kin\source\repos\OS\bin\Debug\net6.0\OS.dll
1>Message: Executing IL2CPU on assembly
1>Message: Kernel Base: Cosmos.System.Kernel
1>Message: Checking target assembly: C:\Users\Kin\source\repos\OS\bin\Debug\net6.0\OS.dll
1>Message : warning : Loading plugs from assembly: Cosmos.Core_Asm, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5ae71220097cb983
1>Message : warning : Loading plugs from assembly: Cosmos.Core_Plugs, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5ae71220097cb983
1>Message : warning : Loading plugs from assembly: Cosmos.Debug.Kernel.Plugs.Asm, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5ae71220097cb983
1>Message : warning : Loading plugs from assembly: Cosmos.System2_Plugs, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5ae71220097cb983
1>IL2CPU : error : Exception: System.Exception:
1>Native code encountered, plug required.
1>  DO NOT REPORT THIS AS A BUG.
1>  Please see http://www.gocosmos.org/docs/plugs/missing/
1>  Need plug for: System.Boolean  Interop+Kernel32.MoveFileExPrivate(System.String, System.String, System.UInt32)(Plug Signature: System_Boolean__Interop_Kernel32_MoveFileExPrivate_System_String__System_String__System_UInt32_ ).
1>  Static: True
1>  Assembly: System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
1>  Called from:
1>Interop+Kernel32::Boolean MoveFile(System.String, System.String, Boolean)
1>System.IO.FileSystem::Void MoveFile(System.String, System.String, Boolean)
1>System.IO.File::Void Move(System.String, System.String, Boolean)
1>System.IO.File::Void Move(System.String, System.String)
1>FileOperations::Void RenameFile(System.String, System.String)
1>OS.Kernel::Void ExecuteCommand(System.String)
1>OS.Kernel::Void Run()
1>Cosmos.System.Kernel::Void Run()
1>
1>
1>   at Cosmos.IL2CPU.ILScanner.ScanMethod(MethodBase aMethod, Boolean aIsPlug, String sourceItem) in C:\Development\CosmosOS\IL2CPU\source\Cosmos.IL2CPU\ILScanner.cs:line 625
1>   at Cosmos.IL2CPU.ILScanner.ScanQueue() in C:\Development\CosmosOS\IL2CPU\source\Cosmos.IL2CPU\ILScanner.cs:line 816
1>   at Cosmos.IL2CPU.ILScanner.Execute(MethodBase aStartMethod, IEnumerable`1 plugsAssemblies) in C:\Development\CosmosOS\IL2CPU\source\Cosmos.IL2CPU\ILScanner.cs:line 276
1>   at Cosmos.IL2CPU.CompilerEngine.Execute() in C:\Development\CosmosOS\IL2CPU\source\Cosmos.IL2CPU\CompilerEngine.cs:line 223
1>IL2CPU task took 00:00:01.0520069
1>Done building project "OS.csproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build completed at 3:12 PM and took 01.271 seconds ==========


Show the message and stack trace of the exception.

How do I show it? I am not familar with VS.

This is the relevant section of your build output:
1>IL2CPU : error : Exception: System.Exception:
1>Native code encountered, plug required.
1>  DO NOT REPORT THIS AS A BUG.
1>  Please see http://www.gocosmos.org/docs/plugs/missing/
1>  Need plug for: System.Boolean  Interop+Kernel32.MoveFileExPrivate(System.String, System.String, System.UInt32)(Plug Signature: System_Boolean__Interop_Kernel32_MoveFileExPrivate_System_String__System_String__System_UInt32_ ).
1>  Static: True
1>  Assembly: System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
1>  Called from:
1>Interop+Kernel32::Boolean MoveFile(System.String, System.String, Boolean)

You're calling methods in the System.IO namespace (File and Directory classes), which are normally implemented by the operating system - but since you're writing your own operating system, these methods aren't defined. You have to implement the functionality yourself.

but i heard in cosmos vfs that there is File and Directory tho...
https://cosmosos.github.io/articles/Kernel/VFS.html

And in your link it says that MoveFile isn't implemented. Read the "Move a file" section.

I fixed the MoveFile to copy and delete

You meant you fixed FileOperations.RenameFile to no longer use File.Move?

yes... it no longer use file.move
